# Yii2 detailView highlight value on condition

Tags: formatting, yii2, conditional-statements, detailview

How is it possible to highlight a value in yii2 detailView based on a condition? 
I've tried this way (with and without `'type' => 'raw'`, `'html'`), but no luck:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => $model->attribute > 1 ? '<b>' . $model->attribute . '</b>' : $model->attribute,
],
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use the `format` property, not `type`:

```
'format' => 'html'
```